# Excluded artifact shows in dependency:tree

Tags: java, maven

My project depends on `org.apache.pig:pig` but I don't want the transitive dependencies of `org.mortbay.jetty:jetty` and `org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api`. I added these two artifacts as `<excludes>` but that doesn't seem to work:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'dependency'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - myGroupp:myArtifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [dependency:tree]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] myGroupp:myArtifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.apache.pig:pig:jar:0.10.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO]       \- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:compile
```

#### Simple showcase pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myGroupp</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
      <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>org.mortbay.jetty</artifactId>
          <groupId>jetty</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>org.mortbay.jetty</artifactId>
          <groupId>servlet-api</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've tried this with: `mvn --version`

- Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
- Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 00:44:56-0800)

Can someone help me exclude this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have artifactId and groupId element values transposed.

Try these exclusions instead:

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Comment: Wow, needed a second pair of eyes. Thanks alot.

Comment: I dont get it, this is same exclusion tag that is available in the POM in the question. What is the difference?

Comment: The original POM has <artifactId>org.mortbay.jetty</artifactId> in the exclusions.  That is the groupdId and not the artifactId.

Comment: Ended up here with the exact same problem : group and artifact were inverted... Priceless maven wisdom here ! :)